# Problem when uploading multipart form data in spring boot with WebFlux and Keycloak

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I am trying to upload multiple files to a spring boot controller (WebFlux) with the following POST-Mapping:

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/files", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
  public void uploadFile(@RequestBody Flux<Part> parts) {
    log.info("Mapping worked!");
  }
```

The mapping works fine if I don't add keycloak. If I add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
   <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and the basic keycloak properties to **application.properties**:

```
keycloak.realm = Demo
keycloak.auth-server-url = http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required = external
keycloak.resource = fileupload
keycloak.credentials.secret = MY_SUPER_SECRET
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = true
```

I always get the following exception:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8;boundary=__X_PAW_BOUNDARY__' not supported]
```

Notice here that other POST requests with **application/json** data are working fine, also GET requests etc. Everything works except file upload :( Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Please share.

Comment: No, I switched to the plain old spring mvc :(

Comment: I too have a problem with Keycloak. Can you help? See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650316/keycloak-secured-spring-boot-mvc-app-jquery-ajax-post-method-does-not-work